# Unable to use <canvas> element inside <div> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, bootstrap-4

I'm not able to add <canvas> animation inside <div> element. With the current code, animation takes full page and I want to encapsulate <canvas> inside <div> so that animation would come in single section.
Something like
<div><canvas> </canvas></div>

```
HTML:
<canvas></canvas>
<h2>hi</h2>
```

```
CSS:
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #121212;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 80px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
  
}
```

Comment: post the entire code , with the animations

Answer (score 1):

Wrap a `position:relative` div around the canvas. Make the canvas not `fixed`  but rather `absolute` to take the div frame as a reference.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: #121212;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.my-canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-canvas">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <h2>hi</h2>
</div>
```